# Android - activity with viewpager and fragments does not resume the portrait layout when rotating the device. Only on Huawei smartphones

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, landscape-portrait

### Introduction

I'am facing a strange problem that is happening only on the new device I am trying: **Huawei P8**.

I can't put a screenshot of what is happening but I will try to summarize as follow:

- The activity has only one layout in folder "layout"
- Some of the fragments that compose the viewpager have both "layout" and "layout-land" layouts for different views depending on the rotation of the device.

### Problem

- Starting the activity in portrait everything works and the fragments have their portrait layout
- Rotating to landscape makes the fragments switch to their landscape layout (if the fragment has its custom landscape layout draws it) correctly
- When rotating back to portrait the problem appears. The fragments that have a specific landscape layout does not switch back to portrait layout keeping the landscape one and the result is:

  **With the device in portrait the layout is drawn with landscape layout (took from layout-land)** which is very bad to see because every view is compressed/stretched unnaturally.

I have tried many smartphones in the years and **this only happens on Huawei P8 (Android 5.0)**

Answer (score 1):

Hm. A long time ago I have a similar problem. It was happens due to firmware problems. What I did? I download Application that switch rotation by volume-up key. That help me to get understanding - where the problem is - in my code, or this is a firmware mistake.

Comment: Yes I did, I got the same issue

Comment: I will try to do the same trying to figure out the problem. Do you remember the name of that application?

Comment: @Link88 unfortunately no. It was a four years ago.

Comment: I have tried to use more than one application that handles rotation without any positive outcome. The bug still remains and now I'm back at the begin.